# how to use HashMap in JRE javaetk 1.4.2

Tags: java, ewon

Basically I am doing project on Ewon Flexy hardware, Ewon hardware only supports jre javaetk, which is quite old. Now I have to use the concepts of HashMap in my project and but javaetk doesn't support HashMap . So is there any way I can use the functionality of latest JRE in older version of JRE?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might (need to) live with **Hashtable** instead.

Comment: Or the `Properties` class

Comment: If it is really a Java 1.4.2 then `HashMap` should be available (`HashMap` was added in Java 1.2). There will be no generics however, but `Map m = new HashMap();` should work

Comment: It's not java 1.4.2, its javaetk 1.4.2 @ThomasKläger

Comment: I just downloaded javaetk from "https://developer.ewon.biz/content/java-0", looked into the included "javaetk.jar" and it contains the class files for "java.util.HashMap" and "java.util.Map". So where is the problem with using them?

Comment: Yes, it is there but still if I use it, then it gives compile time error that change ur JRE to 1.7 @ThomasKläger

Comment: What is the compiler error message?

Comment: What does `java -version` say?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot provide type for key and value but you can use it as follows:
HashMap map = new HashMap() or Map map = new HashMap()